# json parsing error is occur while taking request in the controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

Actually i have a POJO it contains Integer variable, but from request if i send String it is throwing Json parsing exception in before entering to the controller.

my controller is:

```
@PostMapping("/employee/w4/information")
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization", value = "Authorization token", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "header")})
public ResponseEntity saveEmployeeW4Information(@RequestBody EmployeeW4InformationInputBean employeeW4InformationInputBean,@RequestParam("empId") Long empId) throws DataException {
    try {
        return buildResponse(employeeW4InformationService.saveEmployeeW4Information(employeeW4InformationInputBean,empId,getLoggedInUser()));
    } catch (DataException e) {
        return buildError(e);
    }
}
```

Request POJO is:

```
public class EmployeeW4InformationInputBean {

private String firstName;

private String middleName;

private String lastName;

private String email;

private Long dateOfBirth;

private Boolean isFullAmount;

private Integer partial;

private Integer partialPercentage;

private Integer fedFlatAndRate;

private Integer fedAdditionalPercentageAmt;
```

}

In the above POJO "Integer partialPercentage" and "Integer fedFlatAndRate" these are integer but while sending request if i sent as "String" it will throw JSON parsing error:

Correct JSON request Ex:

```
{
   "partialPercentage" = "23";
   "fedFlatAndRate" = "33";
}
```

Incorrect JSON request Ex:

```
{
   "partialPercentage" = "stack";
   "fedFlatAndRate" = "overflow";
}
```

if i send as above incorrect request How can CATCH that with proper message with exception handler.

Comment: Why are you using wraper classed in POJO. You can define **int partialPercentage** instead of **Integer partialPercentage**. And correct Json object for type int/Integer would be **{"partialPercentage"=33}**

Comment: Ya ok, but am asking if we gave "String" value in "int" variable how to catch IOException in controller level.

Comment: For exception handling in controller you can use **ControllerAdvice** and **ExceptionHandler**. You can refer this link -  https://dzone.com/articles/global-exception-handling-with-controlleradvice